# Find the Number of $8$ digits permutation of $2,0,3,4,20,34$ with first digit being non-zero.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Find the Number of $8$ digits permutation of $2,0,3,4,20,34$ with first digit being non-zero.

**My solution:** Total number of permutation when first digit is non-zero is $5\cdot 5!=600$

Let $n(A)=$ Number of ways when $2, 0 $ is grouped, hence $n(A)=\dfrac{5!}{2!}=60$, I divided by $2!$ because we will have $20$ two times (Here I have done permutation of $20, 20, 3, 4, 34$)

Let $n(B)=$ Number of ways when $3,4$ is grouped, hence $n(B)=\dfrac{5!}{2!}=60$

$n(A\cap B)=\dfrac{4!}{2!\cdot 2!}=6$

Now I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: 20 and 24 are not digits. Your question needs more explanation since it is not simply a permutation count.

Comment: What do you mean by an 8 digits permutation here? Presumably this is more complicated than just a permutation of those numbers, since you've got that there are $5\times5!$ permutations that don't start with 0.

Comment: @coffeemath In this question I think $20$ is considered as single number. when we write full number it looks like $8$ digits number for example $23042034$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's simplest to consider them first as permutations, not in the concatenated digit form. And then see how many of those 8 digit numbers are produced.

Let's denote by $X$ the set of all permutations of $[2,0,3,4,20,34]$.

Then define (these differ from your notation, as these are now subsets of $X$)

$$\begin{align}
A &= \{x \in X : \text{2 and 0 are grouped (i.e. in adjacent positions and 2 first)}\} \\
B &= \{x \in X : \text{3 and 4 are grouped}\} \\
C &= \{x \in X : \text{0 isn't first}\} 
\end{align}$$

We want to calculate the sizes of

1. $A \cap B \cap C$ (this will be then divided by $4$)
2. $A \cap B^C \cap C$ (divide by $2$)
3. $A^C \cap B \cap C$ (divide by $2$)
4. $A^C \cap B^C \cap C$ (divide by $1$)

(In paranthesis how to then get the amount of concatenated digit forms this set produces.)

The first one is easy, since $A \subset C$, so we're just left with $4$ objects to permute:

$$|A \cap B \cap C| = |A\cap B| = 4! = 24.$$

In the second we have $5!$ permutations but $4!$ of these are in $B$ so

$$|A \cap B^C \cap C| = |A\cap B^C| = 5! - 4! = 96.$$

The third becomes a little trickier because the set $C$ starts to have an affect, but we can write

$$|A^C \cap B \cap C| = |B \cap C| - |A\cap B \cap C| = 5! - 4! - 24 = 72$$

Here we used a previously calculated value $|A\cap B \cap C| = 24$. The last goes similarly

$$|A^C \cap B^C \cap C| = |A^C \cap C| - |A^C \cap B \cap C| \\
=  |C|-|A\cap C| - 72 = |C|-|A| - 72 \\
= 5\cdot 5! - (24+96) - 72 = 408.
$$

Here we used $|A| = |A\cap B| + |A \cap B^C| = 24+96$.

So the total number of the concatenated digit forms is

$$\frac{24}{4} + \frac{96}{2} + \frac{72}{2} + 408 = 498.$$